# Sound only coming out one headphone in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, 18.10

Every few days, my sound will decide to only come out of the right headphone. I've tried with multiple different headphones, but the problem persists. This happens upon either rebooting or coming out of suspend -- it doesn't ever happen while using my computer.

If I open the sound settings and move the slider far to the left, I can get sound out of both headphones, but it's very grainy sounding.

After rebooting multiple times, the problem usually resolves itself, but I can't find a pattern for what's causing it or causing the fix (i.e., sometimes it takes 5 reboots to fix it, other times it takes sleeping it for 20 minutes, etc.).

I've tried killing alsa and pulseaudio, but that doesn't help. What are some things I can try to narrow down the problem?

Update:

As suggested in the comments, I started keeping an eye out to see if this could be a hardware issue. However, I don't see anything that would indicate this -- in particular, if I don't suspend/shut down my laptop, the sound does not ever cut out (even if I pick it up and walk around with it, etc.). Upon suspending/shutting down, it's about 50/50 for the sound to be messed up (and much higher than that once it's been messed up).

Any other suggestions would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Might the headphones jack be broken? I mean the socket, not the plug? Does it improve when you wiggle at the plug?

Comment: Wiggling the plug around doesn't seem to help (sound is messed up currently). A hardware issue definitely is possible: the speakers seem to work just fine when I unplug the headphones (i.e., sound comes out both sides equally).